# How can I inject knex using inversify?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, knex.js, inversifyjs

How can I initialise knex and use Inversify dependency injector to inject it in

every where that i needed?

Comment: you could make a class to handle one knex instance and then inject it whenever you need it.

Comment: I was trying to follow this article that created a factory for initialising knex but in inverisfy i don't know how can I bind a factory to it's interface

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have never used `Knex` but I'm the author of InversifyJS I will try to help you.

Based on the `Knex` [docs](http://knexjs.org/) you can do the following:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  }
});
```

I also found the TS the types [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/knex/knex.d.ts#L38).

I assume that what you want to inject is the `knex` instance. You could do the following:

```
import * as Knex from 'knex';
import { Kernel } from "inversify";

// configuration
let configuration: Knex.Config = {
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test'
  }
};

// instance
let knex: Knex = Knex(configuration);

let kernel = new Kernel();
kernel.bind<Knex>("Knex").toConstantValue(knex);
```

That way knex would be a singleton. If you don't want it to be a singleton you will need a factory:

```
 import * as Knex from 'knex';
 import { interfaces, Kernel } from "inversify";

 kernel.bind<interfaces.Factory<Knex>>("Factory<Knex>")
       .toFactory((ctx: interfaces.Context) => {
           return Knex({
               client: 'mysql',
               connection: {
                   host : '127.0.0.1',
                   user : 'your_database_user',
                   password : 'your_database_password',
                   database : 'myapp_test'
               }
           });
       });
```

You could also separate the config:

```
 import * as Knex from 'knex';
 import { interfaces, Kernel } from "inversify";

 kernel.bind<Knex.Config>("KnexConfig").toConstantValue({
     client: 'mysql',
     connection: {
         host : '127.0.0.1',
         user : 'your_database_user',
         password : 'your_database_password',
         database : 'myapp_test'
     }
 });

 kernel.bind<interfaces.Factory<Knex>>("Factory<Knex>")
       .toFactory((ctx: interfaces.Context) => {
           let config = context.kernel.get<Knex.Config>("KnexConfig");
           return Knex(config);
       });
```

These solutions provide you with a factory:

```
let knexFactory = kernel.get<interfaces.Factory<Knex>>("Factory<Knex>");
let knex = knexFactory();
```

The factory can be injected into other classes using an `@inject("Factory<Knex>")` annotation.

If you don't want to use a singleton and don't want use a factory then you will need a dynamic value injection:

```
kernel.bind<Knex>("Knex").toDynamicValue((context: interfaces.Context) => {
    return Knex({
        client: 'mysql',
        connection: {
            host : '127.0.0.1',
            user : 'your_database_user',
            password : 'your_database_password',
            database : 'myapp_test'
        }
    });
});
```

The dynamic value injection will inject a new knex instance. Not a singleton and not a factory:

```
let knex = kernel.get<Knex>("Knex>");
```

Please note that I haven't test these suggestions. I hope they will lead you in the right direction.

Comment: the singleton is the proper way, since knex instance will respond for sensible resources like connection pool. This answer is indeed an amazing guide.